# Ajax response wait for future (scala)

Tags: ajax, scala, future, scalatra

if I have a Future[A] as a result (the last line) in router's post("/some") path, the Ajax client can't get the response and exceeds a timeout. Await doesn't work. Future onComplete/onSuccess {...} works ok, but for the server, so how to translate it to the client as a response? (Scalatra framework)

server:

```
post("/stations/test") {
  Future[Int] {
    // parse jsonData ...
    Thread.sleep(3000)
    1
  }.onComplete { x =>
    // do something on server ...
  }
}
```

client:

```
@JSExport
def testFuture() = {
  val request = Ajax.post("/stations/test", jsonData)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onComplete` returns `Unit`. But, you need proper response to be sent from the server to the client. Use `map` on the future to create the response.

```
post("/stations/test") {
  Future[Int] {
    // parse jsonData ...
    Thread.sleep(3000)
    1
  }.map { data =>
    Response(data)
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! If I put response (type of HttpServletResponse) instead of "Response(data)" it works well. Have a good weekend!
and client side should be like:

    Ajax.post("/stations/test", "abc")
      .recover {
        case dom.ext.AjaxException(req) =>
          //...
        }
      .map(req => {
        // handle all status codes
      })